# Responsive layout, stretch div with no content to max-width

Tags: css

```
<div style="max-width:768px;height:auto;margin:auto;position:relative;">
 <div id="fix" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-image:url('../facebook.png');min-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-width:256px;max-height:256px;"></div>
</div>
```

I've been trying to make the div with id="fix" responsive, It wont have any content to display except the background-image.

I want the div to start at 256px if the resolution allows it.

Any ideas? (Maby i'll have to go with javascript on this one?)

Comment: Please display HTML and CSS separately.  And create a jsfiddle.

Comment: What's the actual behavior you're getting from this, and what was expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the min-height/width two times in your code. First off you need to check that the screen is over 256px, this can be done this way in your CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 256px, min-height: 256px){
    #id {
        min-width: 256px;
        min-height: 256px;
    }
}
```

And if these rules can't be matched, you have the standard settings outside of the query. Like this:

```
#id { width: 100%; height: 100%; }    

@media screen and (min-width: 256px, min-height: 256px){
    #id {
        min-width: 256px;
        min-height: 256px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thx. Thought that I could use a "universal" solution to make it adapt to all resolutions. But then I'll go with this example and make one for desktop, tablet and mobile.

Answer (score 1):

you can get resolution like this is javascript...

```
 screen.availHeight //for height
 screen.availwidth  //for width
```

try a conditional statement like this.....

```
 var x = screen.availwidth
 if (x> 2000px) {
 code here to run if resolution is not greater thank 2000px
 } else {
 code here to run if resolution is not greater than 2000px
 }
```

obviously you would change the 2000px to something else. But using this you can find the screen resolution and change div layout using javascript.

But if you are not willing to use javascript you should use CSS media queries

Comment: If you use a Javascript solution, make sure that it runs on a on a resize event, so that it updates when the user resizes their browser. a media query solution is preferred, if older browser support isn't required.

Comment: @Jason thanks, you're right because if you dont do that they it may not be responsive